# SwiftUI custom button and menu not having same size in navigation bar

Tags: button, swiftui, menu, uinavigationbar

In my app, I want to customize the appearance of buttons and menus in the navigation bar.

This is what I did:

For the button:

```
struct BarButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    private let cornerRadiusWidth:CGFloat = 4.0
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(4)
            .foregroundColor(Color.barButtonForeground)
            .background(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.barButtonBackground1, Color.barButtonBackground2]),
                                             startPoint: .top,
                                             endPoint: .bottom)
                )
            .cornerRadius(cornerRadiusWidth)                
    }
    
}
```

For the menu:

```
struct BarMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
    
    private let cornerRadiusWidth:CGFloat = 4.0
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Menu(configuration)
            .padding(4)
            .foregroundColor(Color.barButtonForeground)
            .background(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.barButtonBackground1, Color.barButtonBackground2]),
                                             startPoint: .top,
                                             endPoint: .bottom)
            )
            .cornerRadius(cornerRadiusWidth)
    }
    
}
```

I used them like this:

```
                    // navigation bar trailing
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
// the menu
                        Menu {                  
                        }
                        label: {
                            Image(systemName: displayType.info.image)
                        }
                        .menuStyle(BarMenuStyle())
// the button                       
                        Button(action: {
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "list.number")
                                //.resizable()
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(BarButtonStyle())
    }
```

However, the display size is different in the navigation bar (menu at left, button at right):

[image]

I have no idea why.
The only workaround is to change the padding for the menu, but it's not perfect.
What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` method on each element (in your case the button and the menu). What that does is it makes each element take the most amount of space possible, when there's multiple elements like that, they are distributed evenly. You can further regulate the size by adding a `.frame()` to the parent container. Should work like magic.

Comment: I tried it for both but nothing change. I think the problem is due to the navigation bar behaviour with bar items...